# Issues with Fixed Position dropdown menu on iOS (Safari)

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, svelte

I have a drop-down menu that is fixed and occupies the entire screen. When visible it should completely obscure the content beneath it.

The below CSS is working for this on all desktop browsers:

```
.fixed-menu {
    position: fixed;
    top 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

However, sometimes when you have scrolled up or down on the page on Safari on iOS the top of the drop-down will be ~1px down from the top and you can see a sliver of the content below, which looks very undesirable.

[Tiny gap between top and fixed dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpnfY.jpg)

Apart from this the fixed position is working perfectly on iOS, and it only occurs after scrolling a bit, and resolves if you scroll further - it’s a weird bug I can’t seem to track down!

[How it's supposed to look/looks when issue not present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqrpe.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you're encountering a common issue known as "Safari's elastic scrolling" on iOS, where the content area is overscrolled slightly to provide a visual indication that you've reached the edge of the page. This can cause a small sliver of content to be visible when you have a fixed element at the top.

To work around this issue and ensure that your fixed dropdown menu completely obscures the content beneath it, you can try adding the following CSS rule to your `.fixed-menu` class:

```css
.fixed-menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: -1px; /* Adjust this value as needed */
    left: 0;
}
```

By giving the fixed menu a negative `top` value, you're essentially shifting it up by a pixel, which should counteract the slight overscroll behavior in Safari on iOS.

If you find that a value of `-1px` is not sufficient, you might need to adjust it slightly based on your specific design and testing. You could also experiment with values like `-2px` or `-3px` to find the optimal offset that completely hides the content sliver on iOS Safari.

Keep in mind that working around browser-specific behaviors like this can be a bit tricky, and it's a good practice to thoroughly test your solution across different devices and browser versions to ensure consistent behavior.